# How to avoid duplicate on insert of field values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Good day guys, I have a grade/score table in MySql that students record will be inserted into using php. I want to avoid a student having a score repeated for a term/period. What I mean is that a student cant have two(2) grades/scores for a subject(mathematics) in a term(periodOne) table. How do I accomplish this in MySql or php? here is how my table looks:

```
table periodOne (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  studentId int,
  subjectId int,
  score
)
```

Let me know if you need extra information. Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: use composite primary keys, or first check for existing entries each time.

Comment: Use the mysql `UNIQUE` flag/key for the field(s) that should be unique in the hole table.

Comment: @fireball The auto incremental field(id) is the primary key in this table. Will the composite primary key work with its existence?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a unique contraint in mysql like this : `ALTER TABLE periodOne ADD CONSTRAINT uc_check UNIQUE(studentId, subjectId)`. You will also have to check with PHP that there is no existing row before to do your INSERT

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the attribute as "Unique" by using UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for which you don't want duplicate value.

If your score are dependent on some other table also then you can use Composite Primary Key.

Comment: Correct, Nailed it.